# Adding a condition to the Include tables in linq query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I hava a linq query in my application, which gets data from multiple tables

```
            var checkpoints = await DbContext.Table_B
            .Where(b => (checkpointSourceIds.Contains(b.SourceId)) && (!b.IsArchived) && (!b.IsDisabled))
            .Include(c => c.Table_C)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_D)
            .Include(c => c.Table_E)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_F)
            .Include(c => c.Table_G)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_H)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_I)
            .Include(c => c.Table_J
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_K)
            .Include(c => c.Table_L)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_M)
            .Include(c => c.Table_N)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_O)
            .Include(c => c.Table_P)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_Q)
            .ToListAsync();
```

The Table_J has similar text for the column 'Title' in multiple rows. I need to only get distinct data from Table_J based on the column 'Title'. I tried out the below queries which didnt work out. How should I solve this ?

```
            var checkpoints = await DbContext.Table_B
            .Where(b => (checkpointSourceIds.Contains(b.SourceId)) && (!b.IsArchived) && (!b.IsDisabled))
            .Include(c => c.Table_C)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_D)
            .Include(c => c.Table_E)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_F)
            .Include(c => c.Table_G)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_H)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_I)
            .Include(c => c.Table_J.Distinct()
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_K)
            .Include(c => c.Table_L)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_M)
            .Include(c => c.Table_N)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_O)
            .Include(c => c.Table_P)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_Q)
            .ToListAsync();

            var checkpoints = await DbContext.Table_B
            .Where(b => (checkpointSourceIds.Contains(b.SourceId)) && (!b.IsArchived) && (!b.IsDisabled))
            .Include(c => c.Table_C)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_D)
            .Include(c => c.Table_E)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_F)
            .Include(c => c.Table_G)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_H)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_I)
            .Include(c => c.Table_J.GroupBy(a =>a.Title)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_K)
            .Include(c => c.Table_L)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_M)
            .Include(c => c.Table_N)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_O)
            .Include(c => c.Table_P)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Table_Q)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: What it returned?

Comment: Short answer: it's not supported. Use a projection. Also, this is an incredibly large number of Includes, I hope you're aware of potential pitfalls.

Comment: It is a good idea to specify exactly what EF you are talking about. EF Core 5 includes [Filtered Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include), which would help you I think.

Comment: @GertArnold How to use a projection ? appriciate if you could give an idea